# Changing the color of a mui Divider

Tags: material-ui

I would like to have a MUI Divider that is half green and half gray. Is there a way to do this?

This is my divider:

```
      <Divider className="bg-darkGreen rounded-xl h-3.5" orientation="horizontal" />
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

And this is how I would like it to look:

[image]

Is this possible to achieve??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by `custom css` styling :

```
<Divider className="divider"></Divider>
```

and css :

```
.divider{
          height: 20px;
          border-radius: 2.5rem;
          background: lightgray;
          position: relative;
        }
.divider:after{
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top:0;
          left:0;
          width: 50%;
          height: 20px;
          border-radius: 2.5rem;
          background: green;
        }
```

Here is the demo : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zhfne1?file=src/App.js)

Then you can use `divider` class wherever you need